# iText FreeText annotation auto-resize rectangle

Tags: java, annotations, itext, freetext

i create a free text annotation using this code

```
PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(stamper.getWriter(), rectangle, "Word1 Word2 Word3", appearance);
stamp.put(new PdfName("IT"), new PdfName("FreeTextTypewriter"));
stamp.put(PdfName.DS, new PdfString("font: Helvetica 22.0pt; font-stretch: Normal; text-align: left; color: #ff0000;"));
```

It works. My problem is that when I view it in Acrobat, the width cuts out the text Word3 and only shows Word1 and Word2. If i click on the free text annotation (to modify its text), then it shows the 3 words and expands its rectangle boundary correctly.

Is there some auto-resize feature for PdfAnnotation.createFreeText()? I tried to use BaseFont's getWidthPoint() to get the String width based on the font size and font but that did not do the trick for me. The code creates a free text annotation with ascending and descending as well as some padding on the left and right which i believe contributes to the annotation display getting cut off on the 3rd word.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: I think I found the solution. Use stamp.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0f, 0f, 0f)); to remove the extra ascent descent and left and right padding

Comment: As you don't show how you calculate your values for `rectangle` and `appearance`, it is unclear how we can help doing it correctly.